# How to remove mesh that is not visible?

Tags: mesh

I would like to remove a mesh that I don't see, but I can't zoom in and remove it from the inside

Is there a command that allows you to do this?

External [image]
Internal [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select some vertices, press  <kbd>H</kbd> to hide them, delete what you don't need, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>H</kbd> to unhide.